# Como ajustar inner join no QueryBuilder?

Tags: doctrine-2, zend-framework-3

Ao executar essa query direto no SQL funciona

```
SELECT T2.id, T2.name, T2.description, T2.version, T2.img_thumb, T2.interval, T2.date_created, T1.id_app, T1.is_active 
FROM Categoria T1 
INNER JOIN DetalhesCategoria T2 on T1.id_app = T2.id 
WHERE T1.fk_user = 4;
```

No entanto estou com dúvida como faço para executar essa query pelo QueryBuilder?

Segue o como esta atualmente:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('T2.id, T2.name, T2.description, T2.qtde_users, T2.version, T2.img_thumb, T2.method_payment, T2.interval, T2.date_created, T1.id_app, T1.is_active') 
            ->from('Application\\Entity\\Categoria', 'T1') 
            ->innerJoin('Application\\Entity\\DetalhesCategoria', 'T2', 'T1.id_app = T2.id') 
            ->where('T1.fk_user = ' . $idCurrentUser);
        $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Tenho dúvida se realmente o **innerJoin** esta sendo passado corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O SQL em discussão pode ser convertido no seguinte QueryBuilder do Doctrine:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->select(['c', 'dc'])
   ->from(Categoria::class, 'c')
   ->innerJoin(DetalhesCategoria::class, 'dc', Expr\Join::WITH, 'c.id_app = dc.id') 
   ->where('c.fk_user = :fk_user')
   ->setParameter('fk_user', $idCurrentUser);
$results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

O método **innerJoin()** possui os seguintes parâmetros (trecho extraído da documentação oficial):

```
// Example - $qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('u.status_id', '?1'))
// Example - $qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1')
// Example - $qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1', 'g.id')
public function innerJoin($join, $alias, $conditionType = null, $condition = null, $indexBy = null);
```

Referência: 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html